# JavaScript keypress event validation in Android browser

Tags: javascript, html

This works fine on desktop browser for numbers and special characters validation, but doesn't work in Android browser :

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isAlphabetKey(event)">

function isAlphabetKey(evt) {
    var keyval = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

    if (keyval >= 65 && keyval <= 90) {  //For A-Z
        return true;
    } else if (keyval >= 97 && keyval <= 122) {  //For a-z
        return true;
    } else if (keyval == 8 || keyval == 32) {  //For Backspace and space
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to fix this for Android browser ?

Comment: You can post failed tests to better describe problem. For example "I pressed XXX button and expected "true" but got "false".

Comment: Try `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`.

Comment: Thanks, tried this no success yet

Answer (score 0):

Try `oninput` event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

It's most useful one for immediate input callbacks, but it's not supported everywhere. As a fallback, you can use `onkeyup`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is using jQuery keyup function 
**HTML:**

```
<input id="q" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search here!!">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#q').keyup(function (e) {
    var query = $(this).val();
});
```